# ANTLR4 - Evaluate from L to R, equal-priority

Tags: antlr4

**Parser rules:**

```
expression : L_BRACKET expression R_BRACKET #Parenthesis
           | left=expression op=AND right=expression #And
           | left=expression op=OR right=expression #Or
           | left=expression op=XOR right=expression #Xor
           | left=expression op=IMPL right=expression #Impl
           | left=expression op=EQUIV right=expression #Equiv
           | left=expression op=VAR right=expression #Var
           | op=NEG expression #Neg
           | VALUE #Value
           | VAR #Var
           ;
```

**Input:**

```
a or a and a and a and a
```

**Parse tree:**

[image]

I'd like the string to be simply evaluated from left to right. In other words, only the left node of the tree should have children in this case.

However, currently, `AND` seems to take priority over `OR`, and the aforementioned string is treated instead like `a or (a and a and a and a)`

How do I do so?

Answer (score 0):

```
| left=expression op=(AND|OR|XOR|IMPL|EQUIV) right=expression #Operation
```